# Automatically generate indexes with app engine unit tests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, python-unittest

Is there a way to get local unit tests with `google.appengine.ext.testbed` to automatically generate indexes the same way the dev server does? I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver_index

def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(require_indexes=True)
    dev_appserver_index.SetupIndexes(None, root_directory)
    dev_appserver_index.IndexYamlUpdater(root_directory).UpdateIndexYaml()
```

I've tried adding the `dev_appserver_index` bits to both setUp() and tearDown(). I've tried initializing the datastore_v3_stub with `require_indexes=True` and `require_indexes=False`. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the `init_datastore_v3_stub` method with a `root_path` option as below:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(root_path="your-root-path")
```

The `root_path` is path of a directory that exists a `app.yaml` file.

It raises `NeedIndexError`, if you set the `require_indexes` option to `True`.